# Does "flex: ..." imply "display: flex"?

Tags: css, flexbox

I found many articles and tutorials but can't find specific mentions about this doubt.
Does the use of `flex` imply that the element is also set to `display: flex`?

Or do I always need to specify the `display` property when using other *flex* properties? (will just setting `flex: ..` not have any effect without `display: flex`?)

And if it is in any way implicit, which elements would be set to `display: flex`? Just the flex container or also the flex items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `flex:` properties on child elements (flex items) will have no effect unless the parent (flex container) is set to `display: flex` (or `inline-flex`).

Flex items - that is, the children of a flex container - do not need `display: flex` unless they are flex containers themselves with additional items in them that will be following flex styles.

Comment: I need to stop misreading things today. (No idea if you noticed my answer that's now deleted, but I confused the flex property to be one of flex containers, when it's actually a property of flex items...)

Comment: @BoltClock Haha, I was wondering where your answer went! Cheers.

Comment: Yes that's my case, a flex container (with ```flex:``` applied on it) that is at the same time a flex item. So, as BoltClock says, ```flex:``` is **exclusively** an item-property and has no effect on *flex-containers*, if these **are not** also *flex-items* at the same time.

Comment: @BoltClock♦ Is it true that all elements have `flex` property even if parent doesn't have defined `display: flex` ?

Comment: @Nenad Vracar: Yes, every element has some value of every property, because every property has an initial value, so there is never a property with *no* value (except custom properties). As another example, a display: none element retains all of its properties, even when its box is not rendered.

Comment: @BoltClock♦ Got it, so its there but it just doesn't work unless you set display flex on parent, also to prove your point https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/2182/

Comment: @Nenad Vracar: Yeah. Also, the spec's term for "doesn't work" is "doesn't apply" - the flex propdef says "Applies to: flex items" An element can have a computed value for a property, even when it does not apply. This is also why you might see a list-style on a ul - even though it's not itself a list-item, it keeps the value so that its list-item children can inherit from it.